# Passing data from ajax to php to mysql weird problems

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I asked a similar question earlier, but think I got the wrong point across and learned more about security than fixing the problem I'm having. I am having trouble with my ajax request to post data into a php script and then submit it to a database.

Just to make it clear, the site is local and I will have nobody creating an account besides me and I will be the only one accessing it. I will make it secure once I get this step finished.

Current error I am getting: none, but no data after the success in alert("success" + data)

I have googled/worked for 10+ hours just on this... Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am just learning.

Here is my Javascript:

```
var firstname = String($("#firstname").val());
var lastname = String($("#lastname").val());
var username = String($("#username").val());
var email = String($("#email").val());
var password = String($("#password").val());
```

Here is the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'create_account.php',
    data: {firstname_php: firstname, 
           lastname_php: lastname, 
           username_php: username, 
           email_php: email, 
           password_php: password},
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success" + data);
    }
});
```

create_account.php:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname_php'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname_php'];
$username = $_POST['username_php'];
$email = $_POST['email_php'];
$password = $_POST['password_php'];

echo "$firstname";
// Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","MyDatabase");
// Check connection
if (mysql_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_username, user_email, user_password) VALUES (0, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$password)'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: Please show the internal server error.

Comment: POST http://localhost/create_account.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: `mysql_connect_errno` -> `mysqli_connect_errno`

Comment: changed it, now I get no error and nothing in the database.

Comment: "for 10+ hours just on this" --- o_O First thing to do on every error - check logs.

Comment: @AlekHurst - ok, try calling it again after your query too.

Comment: You might try creating a script that does nothing but insert into the database to make sure that part is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single quote in the wrong place in your query:

```
VALUES (0, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$password)'";
                                                                        ^^^
```

try this:

```
VALUES (0, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything **looks** fine in the javascript and ajax (at least as well as I can tell without seeing the html source as well.

However you have at least one php error; mysql_connect_errno doesn't exist and wouldn't be called in relation to the mysqli connector.

so try this instead:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname_php'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname_php'];
$username = $_POST['username_php'];
$email = $_POST['email_php'];
$password = $_POST['password_php'];

echo "$firstname";
// Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","MyDatabase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_username, user_email, user_password) VALUES (0, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

I haven't used the mysqli connector but other than that it looks fine to me. If it still doesn't work I suggest enabling full php debug info - for example adding this to the top of the php file:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

EDIT: as hanlet stated you also have a single quote/apos in the wrong spot. (fixed in my example code)